# Set a value to default when property is empty

Tags: java, spring

I have a property in a configuration file like:

```
@Value("${MAX_VALUE:#{100}}")
private int maxSize;
```

In a properties file I have:

```
MAX_VALUE=
```

I'm using Java configurations

```
@Bean
public EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer defaultProperties() {
    final EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer defaultProperties = new EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer(
            textEncryptor());
    Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] { new ClassPathResource(jobProperties)};
    defaultProperties.setLocations(resources);
    defaultProperties.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    defaultProperties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    defaultProperties.setSearchSystemEnvironment(true);
    return defaultProperties;
}
```

When the MAX_VALUE parameter is not set I would like it to use the default value. Currently it gives me a 'NumberFormatException: For input string: "" '

Is there anyway to accomplish this or would I have to remove the MAX_VALUE from the properties file to use the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SPEL expression seems to work for null (missing in `application.yaml`), empty value and valid numbers:

```java
@Value("#{'${MAX_VALUE:}' matches '\\d+' ? '${MAX_VALUE:1}' : 100 }")
private int maxSize;
```

Here a String value is created from `MAX_VALUE` using an empty value as a default.

If this value matches an `int` (not-negative) pattern, it is used as is, otherwise a default value `100` is provided.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have empty string to `int` type, but you can change the type to `Integer` and have the `null` check with default value using spring expression language

```
@Value("#{'${MAX_VALUE}' ?: 0}")
private Integer maxSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize Spring Expression Langauge supports terniary operators. I was able to solve the above issue with:

```
@Value("${MAX_VALUE != '' ? MAX_VALUE:#{100}}")
private int maxSize;
```

For more info on [SpEL](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language)

Comment: you can't have empty value for `int` type, probably you should check for `0`, and if the property is not defined in application.yml the app will fail to come up